# Why my app gets 415 http error but postman gets 200?

Tags: android, file, http, post, upload

I have an app that needs to upload many taken photos to a server. I have tried many codes, and this above is the last I used. I am using it behind an AsyncTask. When I try to send a file I get a "not supported media type" 415 HTTP error. I did some tests using the Chrome extension `postman` and I can see how is the header is made:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ssss"; filename="beatles-1600x1200.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

But I can't see how the final header with this code. That's my second android app. My poor knowledge is making it very difficult to resolve this situation. Any help will be very welcome!

```
public String sendOneFile(String url, String fileName)
{
    String responseBody = "";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("image/jpeg"); //("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        reqEntity.setChunked(true);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        switch(responseCode) {
            case 200:
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if(entity != null) {
                    responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                }
                break;
            case 415:
                return "(Com ERRO) Media type not supported.";
        }
        //Do something with response...
        return responseBody;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "(Com ERRO) " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;


public class HTTPconector {
    private DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient;
    Context context;

    //Contrutor para que metodos possam ser usados fora de uma activity
    public HTTPconector(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public HTTPconector() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    }


    public void ClientPost(String txtUrl, File file){
        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(txtUrl);

            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntity.addPart("Image", new FileBody(file));
            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

            mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(HTTPconector.class.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }



    //Verifica se a rede esta disponível
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
        // otherwise check if we are connected
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public String Get(String txtUrl){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(txtUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();

            return readStream(con.getInputStream());

        }  catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }


    public String Post(String txtUrl){
        File image;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(txtUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.connect();

            //con.getOutputStream().write( ("name=" + "aa").getBytes());

            return readStream(con.getInputStream());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "ERRO: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }


    //Usado para fazer conexão com a internet
    public String conectar(String u){
        String resultServer = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(u);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            resultServer = readStream(con.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resultServer = "ERRO: "+ e.getMessage();
        }

        Log.i("HTTPMANAGER: ", resultServer);
        return resultServer;
    }

    //Lê o resultado da conexão
    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        String serverResult = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            serverResult = reader.toString();
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResult = "ERRO: "+ e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    serverResult = "ERRO: "+ e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        return  serverResult;
    }


    private class PhotoUploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Object> {

        @Override
        public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            Log.d("UPLOAD", responseString);

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```